# VB.NET Web Application project encrypting dll files

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web

I'm compiling a web application project which is coming along well. I now need a decent piece of advice on a way to encrypt my .dll files which contains the contents of the app_code folder. Just as I am well aware of how easy it is to use a 3rd party tool to reverse the .dll and get at the code.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate as I am a bit of a novice in this area.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link contains list of obfuscators for .NET.

[**List of obfuscators**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET_)

**Obfuscation** is the process of renaming this meta-data in an Assembly so that it is no longer useful to a hacker but remains usable to the machine for executing the intended operations. It does not modify the actual instructions or mask them from observation by a hacker.

Hope this helps